# unable to use integer string as pixel value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below, I'm trying to get the string `(40*(parseInt($('#2-cat').attr('id')))+1)` to be the pixel height for moving a div. But it is just not working, and I don't really see why - I've put in two other test lines of code, and the server seems to accept that this string is an integer... but it doesn't want to let me use it for the height of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').click(function(){
        //$('p').html(40*(parseInt($('#2-cat').attr('id')))+5)
        //$("#line").animate({"top":"80px"});
        $("#line").animate({"top":"(40*(parseInt($('#2-cat').attr('id')))+1)px"});
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='line' style='height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red;position:relative'></div>
<div id='2-cat'>hello</div>
<p>hellos</p>
```

All can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/platypus117/XyLNG/1/

Comment: Can you just throw Javascript code around in random places like that?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the animate method a big string for your top value.

It doesn't know how to handle it.

You need to calculate the top value first and then pass it to the animate method.

http://jsfiddle.net/XyLNG/3/